# library email alert, sends emails and is not showing the whole subject

Tags: document-library, alert

I am using sp 2010. I have a library and enabled the email alert. When someone adds a new document I got an email. In this email I see a subject with the title of the document. But the title is not completed. It looks like there is some maximum of characters. Is it possible I can show the whole title in the subject or in the body of the email?

This is for example the email subject:

> TestTestT - 1234 123-45678 TestTestTestTestT...

Answer (score 0):

Actually in the default "SPAlertTemplateType.DocumentLibrary" some values are trimmed to 255 symbols.

```
<Limit Len="255" AutoHyperLinkNoEncoding="TRUE" MoreText="...">
```

If you want to avoid it you have to edit SharePoint alert template.

More information about SharePoint alert template here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb897925(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Is there also an workaround, for example a workflow?

Comment: If you want to get alerts about new items you have 2 another options: 1) Create worflow in sharepoint designer with send email activity. Configure it to start on item added. 2) Create ListItemEventReciever and on ItemAdded event send email with SPUtility.SendEmail method.